# Why was the intramuscular route selected for palivizumab administration to infants, instead of the subcutaneous route?

Tags: pharmacology, pharmacokinetics

The majority of monoclonal antibodies administered by an extravascular route to adults are administered subcutaneously.  Does anyone know or have hypotheses about the reasoning behind why palivizumab and motavizumab were designed for intramuscular administration?  A key point may be related to the fact that they are administered to infants as young as one week old, rather than adults.

FDA documents are at this link:  https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/bla/2003/103770Orig1s5033.pdf